# Query MySQL Table with Excel VBA, ODBC Connection

Tags: mysql, excel, adodb

I've got a bit of an issue with Microsoft Excel while trying to get values from an MySQL 8.0 Table. I have some code (below) I got from the net but I keep getting an error message.
I'm quite new at this so I need a bit of help.

I'm on Windows 10 with a 64 bit computer.
*Timeline:* 
→ I downloaded MySQL a week ago, got the 8.0 workbench version and have the connector installed (Connector/ODBC 8.0.12 - X64). 
→ I created a Schema called *sap* in the MySQL Workbench 
→ I created a Table in *sap* called *variance* filled with data 
So far, so good. 
Then, I load up Excel, get the 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library' and 'Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library' create a Module and insert the following code :

```
Sub MySQL()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim SQL As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver}" _
& ";SERVER=" & "localhost" _
& ";DATABASE=" & "sap" _
& ";USER=" & "root" _
& ";PASSWORD=" & "password" _
& ";OPTION=3"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

SQL = "SELECT * FROM sap.variance;"
rs.Open SQL, conn

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

The file is on my computer so localhost works for me, I also tried with "127.0.0.1" 
The database (schema for MySQL) is called *sap* 
The user I'm using is the root user 
And password is password (not really but I'm not telling for real)

Should work, shouldn't it ?
And then, the fatal part :

"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data Source name not found and no device driver specified"

Debug highlights the line 'conn.Open ....

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Excel is 64 bits, you need MySQL odbc 64 bits.  If your Excel is 32 bits, you need ODBC 32 bits (even your Windows is 64 bits).

An easy way to know if your Excel is 32 or 64 bits, open Excel and Task Manager.  In processus tab, see if Excel has (32 bit) suffix.

Comment: I checked what you said, it was spot on  
I downloaded the latest 32 bit connector (turns out it's called MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver) from the MySQL webpage, installed using their MSI installer.  
  
And now everything works fine !  

Thank you !  

PS: 64 32 bit compatibility ? I would never have thought to check for that one...